# git copy Files from [branch] and paste at under other [branch or master]

Tags: git

I created repository as following ...,

```
TestRepo.git
    |
    |_[Branch.Master]
             |____________Master.txt
    |_[Branch.Develop]
             |____________Develop.txt
```

I want to copy `Develop.txt` and paste under `[Branch.Master]`.

```
/// So I checkout Develop first.
$ git checkout Develop
/// Then I push develop.txt to remote/master
$ git push origin develop:master
/// Then I pull remote/master to my local/master.
```

Then I got below result which is not what I want.

```
TestRepo.git
    |
    |_[Branch.Master]
             |____________Develop.txt
    |_[Branch.Develop]
             |____________Develop.txt
```

What I want is like below.

```
TestRepo.git
    |
    |_[Branch.Master]
             |____________Master.txt
             |____________Develop.txt
    |_[Branch.Develop]
             |____________Develop.txt
```

I don't want to be replaced, what I want is just append.

I appreciate your suggestion(s).

Comment: Please review the answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to *add* a new file, you can simply copy the file from the source branch to the target branch.

```
git checkout master
git checkout Develop Develop.txt
```

Then add the file, commit it, and push the branch out.

```
git add Develop.txt
git commit -m 'Added Develop.txt to the master branch'
git push origin master
```